# Mi aplicación crashea cuando intento hacer un update

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Lo que intento es hacer un update en caso de que ya haya un registro con el id de usuario y el id de carta que le paso por parámetro. Tras esto, en caso de que haya ya un registro con esos valores, lo que quiero hacer es actualizar la columna `quantity` (cantidad) sumándole 1, por eso hago una subconsulta. No sé si lo que intento está bien así o se puede hacer de otra forma.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public void buyCard(int userId,int cardID){
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT *" + " from " + MM_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MM_ROW_ID_USER + " = '" + userId + "' AND " + MM_ROW_ID_CARD + " = '" + cardID + "'", null);

  if(c.getCount()>0){

    String query="UPDATE " + MM_TABLE_NAME + " SET " + MM_ROW_QUANTITY + " = ((" +
                 "SELECT  MM_ROW_QUANTITY from " + MM_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MM_ROW_ID_USER + " = '" + userId + "' AND " + MM_ROW_ID_CARD + " = '" + cardID + "'"
                +")+1) WHERE " + MM_ROW_ID_USER + " = '" + userId + "' AND " + MM_ROW_ID_CARD + " = '" + cardID + "'";

    db.execSQL(query);

  }else {
    String query= "INSERT INTO " + MM_TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + MM_ROW_ID_USER + ","
                + MM_ROW_ID_CARD + ","
                + MM_ROW_QUANTITY + ","
                + MM_ROW_LEVEL +
                ") VALUES(" + ""
                + userId + ","
                + cardID + ","
                + "1" + ","
                + "100" +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    Log.d("a","Insertado ");
    Log.d("c",""+c.getCount());
}
```

El problema está aquí:

```
    String query="UPDATE " + MM_TABLE_NAME + " SET " + MM_ROW_QUANTITY + " = ((" +
                 "SELECT  MM_ROW_QUANTITY from " + MM_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MM_ROW_ID_USER + " = '" + userId + "' AND " + MM_ROW_ID_CARD + " = '" + cardID + "'"
                +")+1) WHERE " + MM_ROW_ID_USER + " = '" + userId + "' AND " + MM_ROW_ID_CARD + " = '" + cardID + "'";

        db.execSQL(query);
```

Cuando uso el debugger de android me sale que el string de la consulta es éste:

> UPDATE MMTable SET Quantity = ((SELECT  MM_ROW_QUANTITY from MMTable
>   WHERE ID_User = '1' AND ID_Card = '1')+1) WHERE ID_User = '1' AND ID_Card
>   = '1'

Creo que la consulta está bien, pero no estoy seguro, ¿alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: @Aure_GPN, usa "debuger" también para ver que error obtienes, revisa el LogCat, bienvenido!

Comment: Si deseas desarrollar en Android, es indispensable el uso del LogCat, de otra forma en algunos caso estaríamos tratando de adivinar el problema.

Comment: Muchas Gracias mire el dubuguer y solucione el problema,que eran las comillas simples en ID_User = '1' AND ID_Card = '1',si las quito funciona

Comment: Me da gusto solucionaste tu problema, recuerda que el uso del LogCat puede ayudarte a resolver un problema en segundos en lugar de horas @Aure_GPN , agrega tu respuesta para que obtengas reputación, saludos.